# Find the two largest number in a list when they are same

Tags: python

If I have a list, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 0], and I want to find the the two largest numbers (which are`9`and`9`), how could I achieve that? And, if possible, how can I get their indices?

Comment: The problem is smaller: find the index of the maximum value. With that index, you can temporarily set it to 0 (or even remove it from the list), and repeat the operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#module-heapq) module for this, specifically the [`nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) method:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,0]
>>> heapq.nlargest(2, mylist)
[9, 9]
```

To find the indexes, you need to enumerate the list:

```
>>> mydata = heapq.nlargest(2, enumerate(mylist), key=lambda x:x[1])
>>> indexes, values = zip(*mydata)
>>> print indexes, values
(8, 9) (9, 9)
```